# Highchart js: How to add new value at drilldown series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xb3r650j/2/) how can I add new data on the drilldown series data

Example, this is the default

```
 drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    24.13
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    17.2
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
```

Now I'm trying to add new value but when always undefined I'm trying to call `this.options.drilldown.series.data[2]` doesn't work always undefined

```
drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v11.0',
                        24.13,
                        55.21  //potential_loss
                    ],
                    [
                        'v8.0',
                        17.2,
                        12.42 //potential_loss
                    ]
                ]
            }]
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom properties are saved in options if you define your point as an object instead of an array:

```
            {
                name: 'v11.0',
                y: 24.13,
                potential_loss: 20.12
            }
```

In `tooltip.pointFormatter` this property can be referred as `this.potential_loss`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/cuawm80r/